# oData connected services sends a Patch instead of expected Put verb

Tags: visual-studio, odata

I am using odata connected service in Visual Studio 2019 in a Blazor project.
When I try to "put" an object to my web api, the verb that is being sent is not "put" but instead changes to "patch".

Why does odata connected service send a patch instead of a put?

Example code:

```
enter code here
var container = new Default.Container(new 
    Uri("http://localhost:39267/odata")); 
container.HttpRequestTransportMode = 
       HttpRequestTransportMode.HttpClient;
var job = await container.Jobs.ByKey("232323").GetValueAsync();
job.StockCode = "sdfsd";
container.UpdateObject(job);
try
{
    await container.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Looks like I found the answer.
I need to use container.SaveChangesAsync(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate) to send a put request.